# Strings Comparison fails

Tags: java, android, string

I have a string comparison problem, the if statement always fails.
However I get the right result(variable) "oui" or "non"

```
String result = sb.toString();
String OK_ = "oui";

Log.i("Responce", "" + result);
if (result.equals(OK_)) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                   "Connected",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   "Error"+result,
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Are there any capital letters in result?

Comment: What is `sb`? You aren't providing very much for us to go on...

Comment: *the if statment alawys fails however i get the right result(varibale) "oui" or "non"* how do you determine, that the `if`-statement always fails? And how can you get the correct result, if it does fail? What IS the result? There is no `return` in your code.

Comment: Try `equalsIgnoreCase()`

Comment: Are you sure result would be in lowercase? If not, use equalsIgnoreCase() method. AND START DEBUGGING YOUR CODE

Comment: @brso05 no capiital letter ,

Comment: Can you try `result.trim().equals(OK_)` to avoid any whitespaces ?

Comment: @ChihebNabil please update question with result from `Log.i()`...

Comment: oui if the right user

Comment: I guess `sb` is not an String object and the `toString()` just give you the object string but not the text... What it is `sb`? is there some method called `getText()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In result string there might be capital letters so do

```
if (result.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(OK_)) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   "Connected",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   "Error"+result,
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU now it works fine here the complete Activity                        [link](http://pastebin.com/0kYbADLF)